# how to select an object from a jTable by a click

Tags: java, swing

I have made a class called Clients, that it has like some simple attributes like client_id, client_name and client_age. I have programmed a small GUI with NetBeans that after I input the data from a client by pressing a button I get it displayed in a jTable.

The source code for adding this in the jTable is:

```
for (int i=0;i<customerV.length;i++){
                jTable2.setValueAt(customerV[i].getName(), i, 0);
}
```

I would like that if I click one element on the jTable to be able to add some orders to that client by making using of a jButton. If I program that in a console it would be like:

```
Order order1=new Order("1000","41211")
```

in which the first field is the order id and the second is the order number, so if I want to assign that to Customer 1 it would be like.

```
c1.assignOrder(order1)
```

how I can do that by using java swing? I mean to select the whole object from the element that I click in the jTable

Comment: there is a method name something like jtable.getselected item, is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Set instances of your `Clients` to the table model instead of client names (like: `jTable2.setValueAt(customerV[i], i, 0);`)
- Implement a custom [renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) that will render the client class as needed (e.g. display the client's name) and [set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setDefaultRenderer%28java.lang.Class,%20javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer%29) it to the table. Another (easier) option would be to just override `toString` on `Clients` to return client's name, or whatever you want to be displayed and do not bother about the renderer.
- call [`getValueAt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getValueAt%28int,%20int%29) to get `Clients` instance bound to particular cell in your button click handler.